# How to setText from a separate Thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to setText from within a Thread.

This is my code of the Thread:

```
private class GenerateThread implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
            // generate the first music
            music = generate(prevmusic, prevmusic.length);
            prevmusic = music;

            // write the midi
            writeMidi(music, song);
            textOut.setText("Initialising...");
            });
    }
}
```

in my main code, I use

```
Thread t = new Thread(new GenerateThread());
    t.start();
```

It does not allow me to setText from within the thread. 
Following some posts on internet, I have tried using a handler, but that gave me errors, I think I am double defining Runnable this way.

Handler handler (before main)

```
private class GenerateThread implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
            // generate the first music
            music = generate(prevmusic, prevmusic.length);
            prevmusic = music;

            // write the midi
            writeMidi(music, song);
            textOut.setText("Initialising...");
            });
    }
}
```

How can I setText from within the Thread? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

besides `runOnUiThread` there is also [`View#post(Runnable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) which I would prefer here because you don't need ugly looking references to the outer Activity (`MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread()`).

```
private class GenerateRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // this code is executed in a background thread.
        // generate the first music
        music = generate(prevmusic, prevmusic.length);
        prevmusic = music;

        // write the midi
        writeMidi(music, song);
        textOut.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // this code is executed on the UI thread.
                textOut.setText("Initialising...");
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new Thread(new GenerateRunnable()).start();
}
```

Also don't confuse `Runnable` and `Thread`. A `Runnable` is just an ordinary class with a `run()` method. It can be and often is executed on a new `Thread`. If you want you can also make `GenerateThread` a real `Thread` like so:

```
private class GenerateThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code here.
    }
}
// start somewhere
new GenerateThread().start();
```

And besides using classic `Thread` you could also think about using `AsyncTask` since that is made exactly for tasks that do something long running and need to update the UI afterwards or when there is progress.

Answer (score 3):

One can only update the UI from the UI thread.  [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) will allow you to run an action on the UI thread the next time it executes.  You can do something like:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
      textOut.setText("Initialising...");
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
private class GenerateThread implements Runnable {
   public void run(){
      // generate the first music
      music = generate(prevmusic, prevmusic.length);
      prevmusic = music;

      // write the midi
      writeMidi(music, song);

      // Update the UI
      MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          textOut.setText("Initialising...");
        }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: OK. If I put this code in my main. How do I start the thread? I cannot use Thread t = new Thread(new GenerateThread());
  t.start(); anymore since it is not a seperate class?